# Stateless EJB throwing NullPointerException in Enterprise Application Client

Tags: java, ejb

I am relatively new to Java EE and I am a bit confused as to how I access a stateless Java Bean from my Enterprise Application Client.

My intention is for my enterprise bean, CarReposityImpl, to handle database access and entity management for an entity class called Car.

My CarRepositoryImpl looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class CarRepositoryImpl implements CarRepository
{   
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "FIT5042AssignmentEJBPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addCar(Car car)
    {
        entityManager.persist(car);
    }

    @Override
    public Car searchByVIN(String vin) throws Exception
    {
        Car car = entityManager.find(Car.class, vin);
        return car;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> getAllCars() throws Exception 
    {        
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery(Car.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCar(String vin) throws Exception 
    {          
        Car car = searchByVIN(vin);

        if (car != null) 
        {
            entityManager.remove(car);
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void editCar(Car car) throws Exception 
    {      
        entityManager.merge(car);
    }    
}
```

It implements the interface CarRepository that looks like:

```
@Remote
public interface CarRepository 
{
    public void addCar(Car car);
    public Car searchByVIN(String vin) throws Exception;
    public List<Car> getAllCars() throws Exception;
    public void removeCar(String vin) throws Exception;
    public void editCar(Car car) throws Exception;
}
```

The entity class Car looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Car.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME, query = "SELECT c FROM Car AS c")})
public class Car implements Serializable
{
    public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME = "Car.getAll";
    //private Sale sale;
    String modelNo, VIN, model, make, type, thumbnail, description, prevURL;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String varModelNo, String varVIN, String varModel, String varMake, String varType, String varThumb, String varDesc, String varPrevURL)
    {
        modelNo = varModelNo;
        VIN = varVIN;
        model = varModel;
        make = varMake;
        type = varType;
        thumbnail = varThumb;
        description = varDesc;
        prevURL = varPrevURL;
    }

    public void setModelNo(String varModNo){modelNo = varModNo;}
    public void setVIN(String varVIN){VIN = varVIN;}
    public void setModel(String varMod){model = varMod;}
    public void setMake(String varMake){make = varMake;}
    public void setType(String varType){type = varType;}
    public void setThumbnail(String varThumb){thumbnail = varThumb;}
    public void setDesc(String varDesc){description = varDesc;}
    public void setPrevURL(String varPrev){prevURL = varPrev;}

    @Column(name = "modelNo")
    public String getModelNo(){return modelNo;}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "VIN")
    public String getVIN(){return VIN;}

    @Column(name = "model")
    public String getModel(){return model;}

    @Column(name = "make")
    public String getMake(){return make;}

    @Column(name = "type")
    public String getType(){return type;}

    @Column(name = "thumbnail")
    public String getThumbnail(){return thumbnail;}

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDesc(){return description;}

    @Column(name = "prevURL")
    public String getPrevURL(){return prevURL;}
}
```

From my understanding I should be able to add this line:

```
public class CarSales 
{
    @EJB
    private static CarRepository carRepo;
```

to the class in my Enterprise Application Client that handles my business logic and then I should be able to it to call the methods inside my CarRepositoyImpl bean to access the my database. I am pretty sure I am not supposed to instantiate the carRepo object like a normal object because the EJB container is supposed to handle that.

Essentially I want to be able to use my stateless bean in my Application client like this:

```
List<Car> cars = carRepo.getAllCars();
```

but when I do it throws a null pointer exception and I have no idea why.

My application client class as it currently stands, it is mostly incomplete:

```
public class CarSales 
{
    @EJB
    private static CarRepository carRepo;

    private final MainScreen main;

    public CarSales()
    {
        main = new MainScreen();
        addCarActionListeners();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        displayAllCars();
    }

    private void displayAllCars()
    {
        main.getCarScreen().clearTable();

        try
        {
            List<Car> cars = carRepo.getAllCars();

            for(Car car : cars)
            {//"VIN", "Model Number", "Model Name", "Make", "Thumbnail", "Description", "URL"
                String[] data = new String[7];
                data[0] = car.getVIN();
                data[1] = car.getModelNo();
                data[2] = car.getModel();
                data[3] = car.getMake();
                data[4] = car.getThumbnail();
                data[5] = car.getDesc();
                data[6] = car.getPrevURL();
                main.getCarScreen().getModel().addRow(data);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            main.getCarScreen().outputAddError(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("failed");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addCarActionListeners()
    {//CLOSE
        main.getCarScreen().getClose().addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                main.closeWindow();
            }
        });

        main.getCarScreen().getAdd().addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Car car = new Car(main.getCarScreen().getModelNo(), 
                            main.getCarScreen().getVin(),
                            main.getCarScreen().getModelName(),
                            main.getCarScreen().gerMake(),
                            main.getCarScreen().getType(),
                            main.getCarScreen().getThumb(),
                            main.getCarScreen().getDesc(),
                            main.getCarScreen().getUrl());
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("try");
                    carRepo.addCar(car);
                    displayAllCars();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("catch");
                    //main.getCarScreen().outputAddError(ex.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Stack trace of my error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at CarSales.CarSales.displayAllCars(CarSales.java:45)
at CarSales.CarSales.run(CarSales.java:36)
at CarSales.Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
```

Line 45 is:

```
List<Car> cars = carRepo.getAllCars();
```

Made some suggested changes to my CarSales Class:

```
public class CarSales 
{
    @EJB
    private CarRepository carRepo;

    private final MainScreen main;

    public CarSales()
    {
        main = new MainScreen();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
    {
        addCarActionListeners();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        displayAllCars();
    }
```

My main function that calls run:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CarSales sys = new CarSales();
        sys.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait a minute. Are your trying run your enterprise application as standalone one? You MUST deploy it on some application server and your cannot run your `main` method like that!

Comment: I am running this through glass fish.

Comment: Is this some kind of tutorial which you try to do? I think you are not able to call `main` method in that way. You should create `Singleton` which will call what you want on startup. Or maybe you found somewhere that you can call main method on application server?

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of some resources that properly instruct how to build around my main method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an object yourself, then the container has no chance to perform injection.  In the client container, effectively only the main class is eligible for injection.  Try:

```
public class Main 
{
    @EJB
    private static CarRepository carRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CarSales sys = new CarSales(carRepo);
        sys.run();
    }
}

public class CarSales 
{
    private final CarRepository carRepo;
    private final MainScreen main;

    public CarSales(CarRepository carRepo)
    {
        this.carRepo = carRepo;
        main = new MainScreen();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can declare the reference in your main class, and then look up the EJB reference from anywhere in the client application:

```
@EJB(name="ejb/carRepo", beanInterface=CarRepository.clas)
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

...
CarRepository carRepo = (CarRepository)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/carRepo");
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written I assume you are trying to call `carRepo.getAllCars()` in your `CarSales` constructor. You cannot do this there. Do it instead in method annotated with `PostConstruct`.

You should do this instead:

```
public CarSales() {
    main = new MainScreen();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   addCarActionListeners();
}
```

OK one more edit.
Why do you have your injected bean marked as `static`? It shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: PostConstruct happens immediately after the dependency is established. I also want to be able to access the bean during runtime. Say if I need to search for a specific car in the database or edit the values of a car.

Comment: Then show more code where you call methods from your injected bean with stacktrace of exception.

Comment: So that is what I told you. In constructor you are calling `addCarActionListeners` method and there you are calling method from your injected bean. You cannot do this.

Comment: The line that is generating the NullPointerException is not being called from the constructor though. It is in the displayAllCars() function which is called from the run() function. Run is called independently of the constructor.

Comment: I asked you one more question. Why your injected bean is marked as static? I think this could generate problem because it mustn't be static.

Comment: I removed the static so it is just  
    private CarRepository carRepo; and it still generates the same error.

Comment: I also added the @PostConstruct method but it did not effect the NullPointerException.

Comment: Please edit your code then and post some code where you call your `run()` method.